# Simulating dragging for DIV, issue with fast moving mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to simulate a dragging effect, basically when an user `click` and `kept hold` the mouse on a DIV, it should be re-positioned accordingly to mouse coordinates (following the mouse).

This script works fine:

http://jsbin.com/vurumupoqu/1/

**Except** when a user click and hold *very near the edge of the DIV* and move FAST and far away the mouse outside the DIV, in this case is not being dragged at all.

I have tried several option with `mouseleave` and `mouseout` with not success.

I need the DIV being dragged even if the user move fast the mouse when key is hold anywhere on the page.

I would like to know:

- How to fix this issue? (I meanly target latest Chrome and Firefix).
- Could be a better option using HTML5 drag? If yes why?

Comment: Since you have jQuery tagged in this post, why not use jQuery? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ It's all done for you, all you need to do is tell jQuery what element(s) you want to become draggable. As simple as `$( "#ElementID" ).draggable();` Once you link to the jQuery library.

Comment: Sorry.. I have added my mistake the jquery tag, now has been removed. I need to solve this issue with vanilla js. Thanks for your comment and help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind the `mousemove` event handler to `document` instead of the element itself:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    console.log('+ mousemove')
    this.logicDrag();
}.bind(this));
```

http://jsbin.com/deyiwaqeqa/2/

---

### Explanation

A `mousemove` event is not triggered for every pixel when you move the mouse around. This means that the mouse might have left `#target` - before `#target` has been moved to match the new mouse position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would  rather prefer having the event listener on the DIV itself, as I am planning to have the dragging functionality on multiple DIV on the same page.

Comment: You can bind multiple event listeners to `document`, so this should work even with multiple `div` elements.

Comment: @GibboK: It should have been specified in the question. This is the answer to your current question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An other syntax: document.onmousemove = (event) => {...}